# Buttons on one page calling different post ID not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php

I am designing a page that will have multiple popup options. The section has a custom field that allows the designer to input a Post ID to identify which popup is assigned to which button. The custom field name is pop_up_name.

The section PHP is as follows:

```
<?php include( '_data.php' ); ?>
    <div class="card-trio-inner <?php echo $classes ?>" <?php echo $style; ?>> 
 
<div><a href="#popup"><?php echo $intro ?></a></div>   <!--Pulls from page section (defines the actual CTA) -->
    <div id="social-popup">  <!--Pulls popup from popup page - hidden until button clicked-->
<img id="social-popup-close" src="/wp-content/themes/huh/_static/images/close-button.svg" alt="close">
    <div class="social-popup-inner">
        <h1>
            Pop Up Heading
        </h1>
        <?php 
            $popup = get_post($pop_up_name); // POPUP PAGE ID
            echo $popup->post_content;
        ?>
    </div>
```

THe issue is that when I have multiple buttons on the pave, it pulls the same pop_up_name for each button.

How can I make it so each button pulls the assigned pop_up_name for its respective button?

Here is a sample of the failing code (the top section with the buttons):
https://heyuhuman.com/melissa-test/

You will see both buttons pull the same pop-up (they should be different)

Comment: How are you storing these IDs?  How are you retrieving them?  How are you attempting to associate them with the correct button?

Comment: Although not related to your problem, since you say you are new can I steer you towards the [HTML5 native popup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)? You can instant accessibility and the JS to open them it very, very easy.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a `php` issue. This is javascript / jQuery issue.

If you want a specific pop-up to be opened for each button, you must define a unique ID for the pop-ups.

You can then catch which button was clicked and open the pop-up for the same unique ID.

For example:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="show" data-id="<?php echo $postId; ?>">show</a>
<div class="pop-up" id="<?php echo $postId; ?>">
   <a href="#" class="hide" data-id="<?php echo $postId; ?>">hide</a>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var uniqID = $(this).attr('data-id');
   var t = $(this).attr('class');
   if(t === 'show'){
     $('div[id=' + uniqID + ']').show().css('display', 'flex');
   }
   else if(t === 'hide'){
     $('div[id=' + uniqID + ']').hide().css('display', 'none');
   }
});
```

Comment: Downvoted because two elements sharing the same ID is semantically/structurally incorrect HTML.  As well as unnecessary.  The custom `data-*` attributes exist for exactly this kind of scenario.  You could have `<a href="#" data-popup-id="<?php echo $popupId; ?>">Click Me</a>` and then use that attribute to 1. check if there's an existing `<div>` with an ID of the same value and 2. handle it

Comment: You are correct. it escaped me. I updated my answer.

Comment: @blokberg 
Thank you so much for your assistance. I apologize for my ignorance in lingo :) I think I understand what you are saying but a couple of things are happening: 1 - this line is causing an error: $('# ' + uniqID + ').show().css('display', 'flex'); Not sure if it's due to spacing or the fact that there looks like there is an extra " ' " in there somewhere. 2 - That same line using the # and the uniqID now removes the CSS coding that is applied to hide the popup in the first place (#social-popup) so now when I click the button nothing happens.

Comment: @mmellor Actually, I tried to explain the logic of the process. The way to open and close the pop-up is the same. Sorry for the syntax error. I've re-edited my answer.

Comment: @blokberg that got me where I needed to be - thank you very much :)